# Prove with Induction for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $n$ is even for $1^2-3^2+5^2-7^2+\dots+(2n-3)^2-(2n-1)^2=-2n^2 $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I want to prove by indection, for $n\in\mathbb N$ even:

$$1^2-3^2+5^2-7^2+\dots+(2n-3)^2-(2n-1)^2=-2n^2 $$

what I did first is to check the numbers, so if $n$ is even
lets take $n=2$ so $(2\cdot 2-3)^2-(2\cdot 2-1)^2=-2\cdot 4$
lets take $n=4$ so $(2\cdot 4-3)^2-(2\cdot 4-1)^2\neq-2\cdot 16$

 I did something wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: That's a confusing way of stating the problem - you want to prove if $n$ is even then the equation in (1.) is true, right? It looks like you are asking us to show that $n$ is even.

Comment: Sorry its not clear, $n$ is even ( its given )

Comment: When $n=4$, I think you want to show that $1^2-3^2+5^2-7^2=-2(4^2)$.

Comment: Ah, I need to make $n$ times $(2n-3)^2-(2n-1)^2$?

Comment: No, you need to compute the entire sum. The problem doesn't say $(2n-3)^2-(2n-1)^2 = -2n^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have proven that the base case works.

**Induction Step:** Assume that the claim holds true for $n=k$.

It remains to prove the claim true for $n=k+2$. Observe that:
$$ \begin{align*}
&1^2-3^2+5^2-7^2+\dots+(2k-3)^2-(2k-1)^2+(2(k+2)-3)^2-(2(k+2)-1)^2 \\
&= [1^2-3^2+5^2-7^2+\dots+(2k-3)^2-(2k-1)^2]+[(2k+1)^2-(2k+3)^2]  \\
&= [-2k^2]+[(2k+1)^2-(2k+3)^2] \qquad \text{by the induction hypothesis}\\
&= [-2k^2]+[((2k+1)+(2k+3))((2k+1)-(2k+3))] \qquad \text{difference of squares}\\
&= [-2k^2]+[(4k+4)(-2)] \\
&= -2(k^2)-2(4k+4) \\
&= -2(k^2+4k+4) \\
&= -2(k+2)^2 \\
\end{align*} $$
as desired. This completes the induction.

Answer (score 2):

Let's put $n=2m$ we can then write the sum as:

$$(1^2-3^2)+(5^2-7^2) +\dots +((4m-3)^2-(4m-1)^2) =$$$$(1-3)\cdot(1+3)+(5-7)\cdot(5+7)+ \dots +((4m-3)-(4m-1))\cdot((4m-3)+(4m-1))=$$$$-2\cdot4-2\cdot12-\dots - 2\cdot(8m-4)=$$$$-8(1+3+\dots(2m-1))$$

The sum (in brackets) is now a  linear one (well known to add to $m^2$ - proved by an easy induction, which I will leave to you). Since $-8m^2=-2n^2$ the desired result follows.

Comment: why $n=2m$ if we need the next one?

Comment: @OfirAttia - I'm not quite sure what you are getting at - but $n$ is even, and induction is slightly easier to manage in steps of $1$ rather than of $2$. As $n$ goes up by $2$,, $m$ goes up by $1$. We may also be able to exploit the evenness of $n$, so we make it explicit rather than implicit. The next line simply rewrites the formula with $m$ instead of $n$. As we go on we see that we are able to extract a factor $-8$ - easier to see in terms of $m$ - and that at the core of the problem we have a sum of odd numbers to compute.

Comment: $m$ looks like $r n$ looks like $r\;n$.

Comment: @SohamChowdhury I'd forgotten that - a always use $m$ and $n$ together. I had a friend at school who made $n$ and $x$ look identical in handwriting. It is an important point. Here in England the examiners on the STET paper (essentially for university entrance) comment each year that candidates have made mistakes because they misread their own handwriting in going from one line of theior computation to the next!

Comment: I'm pretty similar to that friend :)

Answer (score 1):

For $n=4$ you need to show  that $1^2-3^3+5^2-7^2 = -2\cdot 16$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(m)=1^2-3^2+5^2-7^2+\dots+(2m-3)^2-(2m-1)^2$

$m=2\implies f(2)=1^2-3^2=-8=-2.2^2$

$m=4\implies f(4)=1^2-3^2+5^2-7^2=1-9+25-49=-8-24=-2\cdot4^2$

Comment: Ok, I need to check it for $(n+1)$? or for $(2(n+1)$?

Comment: @OfirAttia, assume $f(m)=-2m^2$ is true for $m=2n$ and show that $f(m)$ holds true if $m=2(n+1)$